Exporting MXD file from ArcMap to PDF using ArcPy not retaining embedded Excel tables when converted to PDF
How can I alter my script so that the Excel tables embedded in my MXD are displayed when converting to PDF?
import arcpy
import os

mxd_path = r"D:\CROQUIS_PYTHON\MXD"
pdf_path = r"D:\CROQUIS_PYTHON\PDF"

def export_mxd_with_ole_to_pdf(mxd_path, pdf_path):
    # Cargar el documento de mapa
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)

    # Iterar sobre todos los elementos de pgina en el layout
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd):
        # Comprobar si el elemento es un objeto OLE
        if elm.type == "GRAPHIC_ELEMENT" and elm.name.startswith("OLE_FRAME"):
            print("Elemento OLE encontrado: {elm.name}")


    # Exportar a PDF
    #arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, pdf_path)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, pdf_path, resolution=300, image_quality="BEST", picture_symbol="VECTORIZE_BITMAP",
                              convert_markers=True,  embed_fonts=True)

    # Cerrar el documento de mapa
    del mxd


# Directorio que contiene los archivos MXD
mxd_directory = r"D:\CROQUIS_PYTHON\MXD"
# Directorio donde se guardarn los archivos PDF
output_directory = r"D:\CROQUIS_PYTHON\PDF"

# Asegrate de que el directorio de salida exista
if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
    os.makedirs(output_directory)

# Listar todos los archivos MXD en el directorio
mxd_files = [f for f in os.listdir(mxd_directory) if f.endswith('.mxd')]

# Recorrer cada archivo MXD
for mxd_file in mxd_files:
    # Crear la ruta completa al archivo MXD
    mxd_path = os.path.join(mxd_directory, mxd_file)

    # Crear el nombre del archivo PDF de salida
    pdf_filename = os.path.splitext(mxd_file)[0] + '.pdf'
    pdf_path = os.path.join(output_directory, pdf_filename)

    # Exportar el MXD a PDF y cerrar el MXD
    export_mxd_with_ole_to_pdf(mxd_path, pdf_path)

    print("El archivo {mxd_file} ha sido exportado a {pdf_filename} correctamente.")



If you open one MXD and export manually is the result satisfactory? Your parameters for your function have the same name as variables previously defined, that's not a good idea.

When I export manually, the Excel tables are displayed in the PDF but the table does not appear using the exporttopdf script.

Are you running this code in a CMD window, from a toolbox or using the interactive python console of ArcMap (or ArcCatalog)? I've previously had a little trouble with some functions that, for no particular reason, fail when run in CMD but work just fine when copy/pasted into the ArcMap python console. Perhaps change the title of your question to something like Exporting to PDF in arcpy does not include Excel tables to better describe your problem.

I haven't used the old mapping module as much as the new mp module so I can't really test, but from reading the documentation it seems like the table is a DataFrame element and you might need to set some parameters in the ExportToPDF call:

Here's the full documentation
Is there a way to copy the manual export you do as a Python command like there is in ArcPro? That should help disambiguate what you need to fill out to make the DataFrame/Table show up. Otherwise your code looks good and should work.
